# Get a random character from a string

Tags: vb.net, string, random

I need to get a random character out of a string.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? Any code yet? Did <insert search engine here> not help? Or is it just one of those "Hey guys give me code!!!1111eleven" questions...

Answer (score 4):

Get a random number 0 through the length of the string. Ask the string for the nth character.

Some things to try Googling:

- CharAt
- Index
- Rand
- Random

Of course, add "VB.Net" to your search queries. Use what you know, find what you don't.

Comment: +1 For a helpful answer.  Give a man a program, frustrate him for a day. Teach a man to program, frustrate him for a lifetime...

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim str As String = "This is an example String"
Dim rnd As New Random(Date.Now.Millisecond)
Dim index As Int32 = rnd.Next(0, str.Length - 1)
Dim rndChar As Char = str(index)
```